# Apache suddenly stopped working

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost

After using apache in a local dev setup it has suddenly stopped working. I have tried pinging a previously used custom domain and I'm not getting anything.

I have checked the syntax its correct according to apache. I have made sure that my custom domain is in my hosts file. All seems ok.

I have tried this `sudo bash -x /usr/sbin/apachectl -k start` and still nothing. Error or access logs don't show any errors or warnings.

I have also checked the permissions of the folder I'm trying to accesses and it is `drwxrwxrwx` and a random file inside of the folder has `-rwxrwxrwx@` and the parent folder is `drwxrwxrwx   34 _www  staff   1.1K Feb  4 20:06 www`

There were no changes to my httpd file, but I checked it anyways. I tried disabling it `Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf` (which contains virtual hosts) and `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and added one of the previously working vhosts at the end of the httpd file.

Not sure how to proceed as there is no error or flags. The only thing that might have changed are the permissions, but it did work after changing it.

**edit:** should also add that I'm on Mountain Lion.

Comment: So you're just running Apache on localhost, right? What do you get from `apachectl status`? Have you tried restarting it from the `init.d` script? (Should be something like `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`.) What happens when you do so there? Also, does it indicate that Apache is running when you do a `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep httpd`?

Comment: `-bash: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory`. `ping localhost:80` gets me a response but the address given by `apachectl status` doesn't work. `ps aux | grep apache` doesn't return anything, but ps aux | grep httpd says `_www           12397   0.0  0.0  2454312    936   ??  S    12:10PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND` and `root           12397   0.0  0.0  2454312    936   ??  S    12:10PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`

Comment: What happens if you do the following command in a terminal window: `telnet localhost 80`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more troubleshooting and research I ran `file -b /etc/hosts` and to my surprise line endings had changed. For  the `hosts` file to work, the output from the command can only be `ASCII English text`, anything about line endings will brake it and cause your DNS to stop working. To fix it, I ran:

`tr -d '\r' < /etc/hosts > output.txt` and then replaced my hosts file with the new `output.txt`. After that, I used vim to add line breaks again